# Spring datasource connection manager with jmx to expose real time connections count

Tags: connection-pooling, spring-jdbc, spring-jmx

Using `java/Spring/Ibatis sqlserver` is the database and `datasource` is `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` following is the data source object i want to expose real time connection pool count like how many are right now in use and how many in idle and i want to monitor using `jmx` any quick idea how to implement

```
<bean id="wssModelDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource"/>
    <property name="url" value="com.wss.jdbc.ConnectionUrl=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://x-x2/x_control_QA;appName=wss;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;loginTimeout=20;socketTimeout=180"/>
    <property name="username" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="password" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxWait" value="10000"/>
  </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can do it, simply enable jmx for your dao class which have jdbcTemplate injected and being used by dao methods and use create public getter methods returning value of following methods and here you go jmx can  monitor for you.

http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html

```
getMinIdle() 
          Returns the minimum number of idle connections in the pool.
 int    getNumActive() 
          [Read Only] The current number of active connections that have been allocated from this data source.
 int    getNumIdle()
```

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer doesn't really tell you how to do this. If you use Spring, a possible solution is to use the `MethodNameBasedMBeanInfoAssembler` and list the methods on `BasicDataSource` you require to be exposed. Assuming you have a bean configured with id `dataSource` add this to your [Spring XML config](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-instantiation):

```
<bean id="mbeanServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
    <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true" />
</bean>
<bean id="mbeanExporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter">
    <property name="assembler">
      <bean class="org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.MethodNameBasedMBeanInfoAssembler">
        <property name="managedMethods">
        <list>
          <value>getNumActive</value>
          <value>getMaxActive</value>
          <value>getNumIdle</value>
          <value>getMaxIdle</value>
          <value>getMaxWait</value>
          <value>getInitialSize</value>
          </list>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="beans">
        <map>                   
        <entry key="dataSource:name=DataSource" value-ref="dataSource"/>    
    </map>
    </property>
    <property name="server" ref="mbeanServer" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```